# Apply multiple regex patterns on a input and combine the end results

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

I have a string where I need partial data that is located various (start) indexes using regex.

**Input String**

```
Hello, This community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.
```

**Expected Result**

```
community is with specific language problems
```

I have individual regex patterns to grab the info I need. But I don't know how to combine together so that I can achieve my expected result. I could use a loop and then append the previous results through my code. Before that I wanted to see is there a solution so that I can avoid loop.

```
(?<=This).*(?=here)
(?<=you).*(?=coding)
(?<= or).*
```

Comment: What regex flavor and do you have a code environment? (JS, Perl, awk, Python, etc)

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/lOMqy3/2

Comment: @dawg JS code environment

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the response. I see you have substitutions, I'm not sure how to apply that in the JS code. Could you please let me know how I can use it in my JS code.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lOMqy3/2/codegen?language=javascript

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/.*?\bThis\b\s*(.*)\bhere\b.*?\byou\b\s*(.*?)\bcoding\b.*?\bor\b\s*(.*)/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lOMqy3/4).

**Details**

- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bThis\b` - a whole word `This`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bhere\b` - whole word `here`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\byou\b` - whole word `you`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bcoding\b` - whole word `coding`
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\bor\b` - whole word `or`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 3: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

See JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /.*?\bThis\b\s*(.*?)\bhere\b.*?\byou\b\s*(.*?)\bcoding\b.*?\bor\b\s*(.*)/;
const str = "Hello, This community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.";
console.log(str.replace(regex, "$1$2$3"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a combined version of the regex you have given in the explanation.

`.*(?<=This)\s(.*)(?=here).*(?<=you)\s(.*)(?=coding).*(?<= or)\s(.*)`

You can now combine group ***$1 $2 and $3*** to get the desired result.

```js
let inpStr = "Hello, This community is here to help you with specific coding, algorithm, or language problems.";

let regex = /.*(?<=This)\s(.*)(?=here).*(?<=you)\s(.*)(?=coding).*(?<= or)\s(.*)/;

console.log(inpStr.replace(regex,"$1$2$3"));
```